# Как нарисовать плоскую фигуру в sympy/matplotlib в режиме 3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

Мне нужно нарисовать две окружности.

Между плоскостями, на которых лежат окружности есть некоторый угол. Например 40° вдоль оси Z.

```
plot3d_parametric_line(cos(u),sin(u),0,(u,-5,5))
```

выдает

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Программа:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy.vector import *
M = Matrix([[1,0,0],
            [0,1,0],
            [0,0,1]])
N = Matrix([[0,0,1],
            [1,0,0],
            [0,1,0]])
HC = Matrix([R*cos(alpha),R*sin(alpha),z])
FC1 = M*HC
FC2 = N*HC
p1 = plot3d_parametric_surface(FC1[0].subs(R,50),FC1[1].subs(R,50),FC1[2])
p2 = plot3d_parametric_surface(FC2[0].subs(R,50),FC2[1].subs(R,50),FC2[2].subs(R,50))
p1 = p1.append(p2[0])
```

Это моя попытка. И она не работает. Здесь рисует два цилиндра в разных окнах. Нужно зафиксировать z.

Comment: Итак, у меня открываются два окна поочерёдно с цилиндрами, один из них вертикально расположен, а другой - как-бы лежит. Последнюю строчку скрипта я исправил на `p1.append(p2[0])`, что теперь при вызове функции `print(p1)` выдаёт мне: "Plot object containing:
[0]: parametric cartesian surface: (50*cos(alpha), 50*sin(alpha), z) for z over (-10.0, 10.0) and alpha over (-10.0, 10.0)
[1]: parametric cartesian surface: (z, 50*cos(alpha), 50*sin(alpha)) for z over (-10.0, 10.0) and alpha over (-10.0, 10.0)"

Что значит "зафиксировать z". Просто не понял задачи

Comment: Просто мне не цилиндры нужны, а окружности)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это

```py
plot3d_parametric_line(cos(u), sin(u), u, (u, -5, 5))
```

Comment: это уже не плоская фигура. Пробовал

Comment: Покажи полный код программы

Comment: В вопросе поправил